# Issue after doing a query, I'm getting other values in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I wrote an app in Rails and created a query to count the `last_insurance` and sum by `type_money` but when I show it in my `text_field_tag` I'm getting another value:

```
#######this error is inside my text_field_tag
      #<Policy:0x7feed11412d0>
```

Here is the description of the query:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f5c/1
```

Here are my models:

```
class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :policy
end

class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
 unloadable
 has_many :insurances
end
```

This is my controller:

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
  def generate_print_calculator
     @dolar = Policy.find_by_sql("SELECT sum(i1.net_insurance) total 
                                 FROM (
                    SELECT max(id) id FROM insurances
                    GROUP BY policy_id
                ) i2
            JOIN insurances i1 USING (id)
              JOIN policies p ON p.id = i1.policy_id
            WHERE p.type_money = 1  
            GROUP BY p.type_money")       
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
Suma Dólars : 
<%= text_field_tag "dolar", @dolar %>
```

When I tried this in MYSQL I got:

```
           |total|
   426913.49999999977
```

And, when I show `@dolar` in my view I got this inside my textfield:

```
#<Policy:0x7feed11412d0>
```

`@dolar` is not showing in my view and I'm getting another value. Also, when I refresh it I'm getting another strange value:

```
  #<Policy:0x7feed0e05440>
```

Here is an example what I tried with less policies and is working:

```
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f5c/1
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: In your view, try <%= @dolar.inspect %>. Whats the outcome?

Comment: I tried your code and i got "nil" inside my textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `<%= text_field_tag "dolar", @dolar.first.total %>` in your view.

`@dolar.first.total` looks better then `@dolar[0].total`...just a visual thing no change in output

Comment: I tried your code and i got
undefined method `total' for [#<Policy >]:Array

Comment: what all columns are you fetching in the query, and what column you want to print??

Comment: I guess you want `type_money` value in your text right..???if so replace the total with `type_money`

Comment: i replaced it for type_money and i got undefined method `type_money' for [#<Policy >]:Array

Comment: I want to see results from my query in my view

Comment: see, your query returns you an `Active Record` object....to show the object you need to parse the object. you cant directly show the whole query output as is..

Comment: Ok ,how can i fix this?

Comment: Ohh...your active record object is an array, you need to so `@dolar[0].total` or `@dolar[0].type_money`

Comment: FANTASTIC sir!!! @dolar[0].total it worked for me :) i really appreciate your help .You won 1 point and my thanks.
I have a final question do you need to post your final answer or will you edit your answer to give you 1 point?